# Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file with Application Loader

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, application-loader

I am using visual studio 2017 on windows. I am getting the above error using the Application Loader when uploading the .IPA file. I have the Asset Catalogs file in the root of my IOS project. There is nothing showing in Assets. we added all App icons to solution. Does anyone have any insight into why I am my asset catalog is missing or steps I can do to ensure it is included.[image]

thanks

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/107175/missing-asset-catalog-your-app-is-missing-the-asset-catalog-file-in   is this question you post?

Comment: Not Exactly, i am trying to upload my IPA file to iTunes, But facing Asset catalog is missing issue

Comment: The IPA file which we generated with Ad-Hoc profile which is working fine with Devices, But the IPA file with is generated with Distribution profile facing issue

Comment: Hi, for issues like this it's good to report them directly within the IDE (this is where the Xamarin team is tracking issues). Simply use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to file your issue.

Comment: Otherwise a test case of you project would help. The questions that come into my mind are: Does your Info.plist use the Asset.xcasset for app icons? If you double click on the Asset Catalogs do you see your assets? What about the csproj can you gist it (does it include the app icons assets)? Are there physical assets in you xcassets folder?